# Postgres COPY FROM ... WITH BINARY returns an error "literal carriage return found in data"

Tags: postgresql, plsql, copy

I have two functions. One that copies variable (uuid) to a binary file on one database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ECRS."MIGRATION.DBF_COPY_TO"(file_name VARCHAR(500))
    RETURNS INTEGER AS $$

DECLARE 
iniPath varchar(500) = file_name || '/Ini.dat';
researchIdToCopy uuid;

BEGIN
    SELECT R.RESEARCHID FROM ECRS.RESEARCH R WHERE R.NAME = 'BADANIE_TESTOWE' INTO researchIdToCopy;

    EXECUTE('COPY (SELECT '''|| researchIdToCopy ||''') TO ' || quote_literal(iniPath)|| ' WITH BINARY');

RETURN 1;
END; $$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The secound one is responsible for copying this data from file and store it into variable on another postgress database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ECRS."MIGRATION.DBF_COPY_FROM"(file_name VARCHAR(500))
    RETURNS INTEGER AS $$

DECLARE 

iniPath varchar(500) = file_name || '/Ini.dat';

researchIdToInsert text;
tmp text;


BEGIN

-- get research id (store ini file in tmp table and select from it)
tmp := quote_ident(uuid_generate_v4()::text);
EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMP TABLE ' || tmp || ' (researchid text)';
EXECUTE 'COPY ' || tmp || ' FROM ' || quote_literal(iniPath);
EXECUTE 'SELECT researchid FROM ' || tmp INTO researchIdToInsert;
EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE ' || tmp;

-- DO SOMETHING MORE ...


RETURN 1;
END; $$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I get an error executing function DBF_COPY_FROM:

```
ERROR:  literal carriage return found in data
HINT:  Use "\r" to represent carriage return.
CONTEXT:  COPY f4c96770-f2f3-45e9-8678-1626b9bef843, line 2
SQL statement "COPY "f4c96770-f2f3-45e9-8678-1626b9bef843" FROM 'C://Test/Ini.dat'"
PL/pgSQL function ecrs."MIGRATION.DBF_COPY_FROM"(character varying) line 29 at EXECUTE
```

Both databases have the same properties :

- ENCODING = 'UTF8'
- TABLESPACE = pg_default
- LC_COLLATE ='English_United Kingdom.1252'
- LC_CTYPE = 'English_United Kingdom.1252'
- CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

I have tried to use 
set client_encoding to 'WIN1252';
or
set client_encoding to 'UTF8'; but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that you write a file with `MIGRATION.DBF_COPY_TO` and then read it with `MIGRATION.DBF_COPY_FROM`?

If yes, that's not going to work, because the first function uses the binary format, while the second function uses the text format.

Carriage return characters without following line feed are not allowed in text mode `COPY`, but in this case it is a consequence of you using different formats for input and output.